# install.packages installs far more than package_dependencies

Tags: r, installation-package

It seems `package_dependencies` doesn't report all the dependencies,
or `install.packages` is going way, way overboard.

For example, in a new install of R 3.5.0 from source on Ubuntu 16.04,
package_dependencies shows only 3 dependencies for `colorspace`.  But when I 
install `colorspace`, 22 other packages are yanked in.

```
$ /sdata/ftp/rlang/tdi/bin/R --vanilla

...(R announcements)

.libPaths()
[1] "/sdata/ftp/rlang/tdi/lib64/R/library"
library( tools)
avail <- available.packages( repos="https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran")
package_dependencies("colorspace", recursive=TRUE, db=avail)
$colorspace
[1] "methods"   "graphics"  "grDevices"



install.packages("colorspace", dependencies=TRUE,
   lib="/some/empty/dir",
   repos="https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran")
also installing the dependencies ‘zoo’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘BH’, ‘magrittr’,
‘lmtest’, ‘httpuv’, ‘mime’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘xtable’, ‘digest’,
‘htmltools’, ‘R6’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘crayon’,
‘rlang’, ‘kernlab’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘vcd’, ‘dichromat’, ‘shiny’, ‘shinyjs’
```

Why are all these packages being yanked in?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html

Comment: see ?install.packages for how "TRUE" is interpreted for dependencies argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting `dependencies=TRUE` (rather than the default value of `NA`) you're getting not just imports/depends/linkingto, but also all of the *suggested* packages: from `?install.packages`,

> ... ‘TRUE’ means to use ‘c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo",
>             "Suggests")’ for ‘pkgs’ and ‘c("Depends", "Imports",
>             "LinkingTo")’ for added dependencies: this installs all the
>             packages needed to run ‘pkgs’, their examples, tests and
>             vignettes (if the package author specified them correctly).

The analog for `package_dependencies` is `which="all"`.

```
length(package_dependencies("colorspace",
         recursive=FALSE,which="all")$colorspace)
## 15

length(package_dependencies("colorspace",
         recursive=TRUE,which="all")$colorspace)
## 1278
```

The reason you're getting 22 (and not 15 or 1278) new packages installed is a combination of (1) some packages are already installed (e.g. the 15 direct Suggests: dependencies include at least 6 base/recommended packages) and (2) as described above in the documentation block, `install.packages()` does not apply the Suggests: requirement recursively - you get all of the direct Suggests: dependencies, but only the 2d-order dependencies *required* (not suggested) to make them work. Take a look at

```
lapply(package_dependencies("colorspace",
      recursive=FALSE,which="all")$colorspace, 
    package_dependencies)
```

(`shiny` and `shinyjs` are the real culprits ...)

It would be nice if there were a version of `package_dependencies` that gave the same results as `install.packages(...,dependencies=TRUE)`, i.e. took all suggested packages at the first level but then proceeded recursively to find all required packages. (This might be a good homework assignment for an intermediate R course ...)

---

OK, I went a little crazy. I count 24, not 22, that should have to be installed ... ? (I looked at the difference: you're getting 23, not 22 extra packages, and the 24th is `colorspace` itself ...)

```
a1 <- available.packages()
i1 <- installed.packages()
order1 <- package_dependencies("colorspace",
                               db=a1,
                               recursive=FALSE,
                               which="all")$colorspace

order2 <- plyr::llply(order1,
                      package_dependencies,
                      db=a1,
                      recursive=TRUE,
                      .progress="text")

all_pkgs <- unique(c(order1,unlist(order2,recursive=TRUE)))
base_pkgs <- rownames(i1)[!is.na(i1[,"Priority"])]
setdiff(all_pkgs,base_pkgs)
```